# Pretty printing nested syntax quotes

Tags: clojure, quote

Is there a way to print the result of evaluating nested syntax quotes in a legible manner as in SBCL?  This would be useful when debugging nested syntax quotes when writing macros.  For instance, in Clojure 1.8,

```
(let [x '(1 2)] ``(~~@x))
```

evaluates to

```
(clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list 1 2)))
```

In SBCL 1.3.6, the equivalent expression

```
(let ((x '(1 2))) ``(,,@x))
```

evaluates to the much more legible

```
`(,1 ,2)
```

The difference becomes larger with more complex expressions.  Are there any Clojure packages or other methods that can help with this situation?  Currently, the best way I've found to debug complex syntax quotes is to convert them to Common Lisp but this is a rather ridiculous and slow approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you look the function syntaxQuote(Object form)in the LispReader Class of Clojure : 
https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L1011

```
ISeq seq = RT.seq(form);
if(seq == null)
  ret = RT.cons(LIST,null);
else
  ret = RT.list(SEQ, RT.cons(CONCAT, sqExpandList(seq)));
```

you'll see that `(~@'(some list)) is read as :

```
(clojure.core/seq
  (clojure.core/concat
    (clojure.core/list (quote clojure.core/some))
    (clojure.core/list (quote clojure.core/list))))
```

Which is evaluated by the REPL as :

```
=> (some list)
```

Just look at the effect of ` alone

`````
`s => user/s ; it's the ref of the symbol ok
``s 
=> (quote user/s) ; it's the quoted ref 
```s
=> (clojure.core/seq ; now we manage a back-tick on a list
     (clojure.core/concat
       (clojure.core/list (quote quote)) 
       (clojure.core/list (quote user/s))))
````s
=> 
(clojure.core/seq ; oups! always a list we add a layer
 (clojure.core/concat
  (clojure.core/list (quote clojure.core/seq))
  (clojure.core/list
   (clojure.core/seq
    (clojure.core/concat
     (clojure.core/list (quote clojure.core/concat))
     (clojure.core/list
      (clojure.core/seq
       (clojure.core/concat
        (clojure.core/list (quote clojure.core/list))
        (clojure.core/list
         (clojure.core/seq
          (clojure.core/concat
           (clojure.core/list (quote quote))
           (clojure.core/list (quote quote))))))))
     (clojure.core/list
      (clojure.core/seq
       (clojure.core/concat
        (clojure.core/list (quote clojure.core/list))
        (clojure.core/list
         (clojure.core/seq
          (clojure.core/concat
           (clojure.core/list (quote quote))
           (clojure.core/list (quote user/s)))))))))))))
`````

And now adding the splicing

`````
````~s => (clojure.core/seq ; same as ```s
            (clojure.core/concat
              (clojure.core/list (quote quote)) 
              (clojure.core/list (quote user/s))))
````~~s => (quote user/s) ; same as ``s
`````

So what are the remarks to make

1. Clojure writer doesn't render quotes as received by the reader macro
   so it gives `(quote s)` instead of `'s`. This is done for arrays, set, ...
2. The back-tick macro reader doesn't make simplification on list/quote matching. Concatenation of only quoted lists and single entries should be executed immediately, giving

   ````~~s => ''s.
3. The problem is even worse if you manage back-ticking on lists or arrays or sets... ;)

The problem is that `s is not 's.

If I remember in LISP `s gives 's as a result. ;)

A possibility to manage a simplified version can be viewed so

```
(clojure.core/seq
  (clojure.core/concat
    (clojure.core/list (quote quote)) 
    (clojure.core/list (quote user/s))))
```

could be changed in the macro generation as

```
(seq 'user/s)
```

But!!! the result is a sequence, say a lazy sequence, not `'user/s`.

Let's try on ````s. simplifying would give :

```
(seq '(clojure.core/seq 'user/s))
```

The result is equivalent to `''s`, but it isn't the same object.

Another thing, we have to manage the `toString` of (quote ...) as '...

And contrary to LISP `'s` is `s` and `s is user/s !!!

And for macro management, it makes a lot of changes... Say 's is in the execution namespace, `s is in the compilation namespace, executed by the reader.

Comment: I assume that you meant `\`\`(some list)` instead of `\`(some list)`.  This could evaluate to `\`(clojure.core/some clojure.core/list)`.  Symbol resolution isn't a problem since the symbols are fully qualified.

Comment: @Qudit I modified the response to grasp more precisely the problem.

Comment: It's of course true that Clojure generates very ugly code from nested syntax quotes but there's no fundamental reason why it (or a pretty-printing syntax quote package) couldn't do something more like what happens with SBCL. Syntax quotes just need to expand to code that behaves in a certain way. There's nothing special about the particular code that Clojure generates for this purpose.

Comment: I add som complementary stuff, because on the comment the format is not readable.

Comment: I hope I didn't miss the explanation, it can be a little confusing. That's why macro management can lead to non-obvious problems. The backtick is a reader macro, so the transformation is done on reading, compiled macro has already the transformed stuff which can be confusing if there are multiple nested levels. The quote doesn't exist... it's just the value as it is, the quote is for the programmer, the program has just the value.

Comment: I understand how syntax quotes in Clojure. The question was about if anyone has a method of printing them legibly for debugging purposes. Currently, I debug complex Clojure syntax quotes by converting them to Common Lisp. (Yes, I know it's not the same but it is usually close enough for debugging purposes.) Obviously, this is a clumsy way of doing things. Surely, there is a better method.